# Titanium mobile - Common JS. Objects values are lost when lauching a fireEvent

Tags: object, titanium, undefined, titanium-mobile, commonjs

I'm dev an app into titanium mobile in javascript. 
The dynamic menu insert each new object(id,text,...., page) into a loop for (var x in tab).

with thoses items, specifics views are made.

var items = [];
    var menuIconsItem = require('view/module/menuIconsItem');

```
for(var i in itemTab) {
    var page = itemTab[i].page;

    items[i] = new menuIconsItem(itemTab[i]);

    menuFirstLine.add(items[i]);
    (function(itemsEvent) {
        itemsEvent.addEventListener('click', function() {

            Ti.App.fireEvent('test' +i, {
                id : i
            });
        })
    })(items[i]);

}
```

on the other controller side, i only get the last id reference.

If i = 0 to 5, i only get the last reference. The rest is undefined.

How could i do please?

Comment: What happens with when you use `items[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

            Ti.App.fireEvent('test' +i, {
                id : i
            });
        })`

Comment: if they are 5 items, it launch the last listener, so 'test5' and the id is 5. This for all items.

Comment: did you alert(e.source.id) inside your evnetlistener? Use `e` as well in function params.  itemsEvent.addEventListener('click', function(e) {});

Comment: The listener won't remember the `i`, you have to check the source id and then pass fire your custom event.

Comment: on the event "fireside" i got this :
(function(itemsEvent) {
   itemsEvent.addEventListener('click',  function(e) {

    Ti.App.fireEvent('test', e);
   })
  })(items[i]);

on the app. listener side :

for(var i in menuItemsTab) {
   Ti.App.addEventListener('test', function(e){
    
    alert(e.source.id);
    
   });
 }

the result is :
[WARN] Exception in event callback. {
    line = 22;
    message = "'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'e.source.id')";
    name = TypeError;
    sourceId = 191404704;
}

Comment: The solution with e.source gives me something to try, thanks a lot!!!
@Muhammad Zeeshan +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to set `id` for your menuIconsItem, I am taking button an an example here.

```
items[i] = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        id:"button_"+i,
        _index: i
})
```

Then do this:

```
(function(itemsEvent) {
       itemsEvent.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

           alert(e.source.id);
       })
 })(items[i]);
```

Comment: This is perfect, don't have the reputation to vote yet. but i won't forget ^^

Comment: This event is added to a view item, that contains 2 components:
imageView (an icon) and a label (for the text).
so i go an item (createView)
on this i made item.add(img); item.add(label) before making item.addEventListener

My problem is that when i click where the icon or the label are, i go and error "uncaught typeerror cannot read property of undefined event", when i click somewhere else, no problem this is working perfect. 

The event listener is on the view only, do you know how i could solved this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551307/titanium-mobile-addeventlistener-on-a-view